# How to combine 2 object model in Promise?

Tags: express, object, mongoose, promise

I have 2 objects (Account, and AccountMeta), and when I join console.log it works but when I make the final result on res.json only 1 data appears, the rest goes to error scope,

what's wrong with my code?

this is my code

```
 exports.get_Account = async (req, res) => {
  const accounts = await Account.find();

  accounts.map(account => {
    AccountMeta.find({ account_id: account._id }, err => {
      if (err instanceof mongoose.Error.CastError) {
        return res.status(422).send({
          error: 'Something wrong with your ID, please check ' + err.message
        });
      }
    })
      .then(resultMeta => {
        console.log('resultMeta \n ', resultMeta);
        console.log('account \n ', account);
        const new_account = {};
        resultMeta.map(editMeta => {
          new_account[editMeta.key] = editMeta.value;
        });
        // console.log('new account \n ',new_account)

        let dynamicAccount = Object.assign({}, account._doc, new_account);
        console.log('dynamic account \n ', dynamicAccount)
        res.json(dynamicAccount);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('err \n');
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: What are the two objects you want in your response (`dynamicAccount` and ?)

Comment: Can you please show us the `console.log(resultMeta)` and `console.log('account \n ', account);`? Also, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: sorry sir, actually i have finished my code. i change the method from promise handling into async/await. then in the end of code i using promise.All..